# method for determining data for google tracking manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method for defining data for google tracking manager. First logic organized in views, but I don't think this is right. Should I put the method in the controller(application_controller) or in the model?

```
def gtm_data(data_hash = nil)
  @gtm_data ||= {}

  if @dynamic_page
    gaPageUid = 'category-' + @dynamic_page.uid
  elsif @product
    gaPageUid = 'product'
  else
    gaPageUid = 'other'
  end

  @gtm_data = {
   gaLocale: @locale, gaLanguage: @lang,
    gaRegion: current_site.region, gaPageUid: gaPageUid
  }

  # setter call
  @gtm_data.merge!(data_hash) if data_hash

  @gtm_data
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you probably want to pull that out of your view. You could consider adding it to `application_controller` (or a more specific controller if you don't need it everywhere in your app) and expose a helper method. Basically all you would have to do is add your method to `application_controller`, as well as this:

`helper_method :gtm_data`

You could also put the code in `application_helper`, which is the way I personally would do it. Might have trouble passings args to a helper method exposed in a controller

Comment: Thanks, one more question, is it worth to test(rspec) this method?

Comment: Yep, I would definitely write tests to make sure the expected hash is being returned with a few different inputs

Comment: Could you help me with writing the test?

Comment: Not really. It would involve setting up a test framework and importing helpers/controllers. The Rspec docs are good, should you decide to go that route. Then it's a matter of `expect(gtm_data(some_args)).to eq({'your': 'hash'})`